# Getting "can't cd" error when when building using dockerfile

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

This is the complete dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

# Create directory 
RUN mkdir -p /dir/subdir

# Download wget
RUN apt-get install -y wget

# Make sure package is up to date
RUN apt-get update

# Install nodejs
WORKDIR /dir
RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxf node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 && ./configure
RUN cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 && make
RUN cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 && make install

# Update again
RUN apt-get-update

# Copy all the files 
ADD dir/subdir dir/subdir

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "/dir/subdir/index.js"]
```

This is part of the log where it gets an error

```
Step 6 : RUN tar -zxf node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz 
---> Running in xxxxxxx 
---> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Removing intermediate container xxxxxxxxxxxx
Step 7 : RUN cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 && ./configure 
---> Running in xxxxxxxx
[91m/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64
 [0m 
The command [/bin/sh -c cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64 && ./configure] returned a non-zero   code: 2
```

Does anyone know what the error 2 means and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post an actual Dockerfile and the logs of your error? error code 2 is usually a shell error, but could be anything. The logs will tell you.

Comment: I find the best way to debug dockerfiles is to comment out the problem line and everything past it.  Then build the image and start up a sh session in it.  Try running the command manually.

Comment: yeah Ill do it on a sec

Comment: Also since you don't need to get past auth, you can compress RUN wget and RUN tar with an ADD, ADD will download and untar/gz a tar.gz url.

Comment: I added my dockerfile, so The only command I need is this:
ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: Also I am trying to install it in the directory 'dir' So do I need the
WORKDIR /dir command?

Comment: The incorrect line is the `cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64`, instead add another line: `WORKDIR /dir/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64` and skip the `cd`s

Comment: @generalhenry How do I run a command manually after I create the image?

Comment: 1) comment out failing line and below  2) `docker build -t my_name_here .` 3) `docker run -i -t my_name_here bin/bash` 4) run the failing command in the container bash session.   docker files work by creating a container for each line running the command then committing.  You want to replicate that process but intercept the run part (since it's failing)

Comment: @generalhenry I am getting permission denied.Do I run the commands on the same directory my dockerfile is at? btw thanks for all your help

Comment: You don't need to run the commands from the same directory as the Dockerfile, you just need to specify it.  In my directions I assumed same directory, hence `.` just change the `.` to the directory with your Dockerfile.

Comment: @generalhenry so I ran the command that is failing and it gives me the following error bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: I tried it out.  http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz is the linux distribution. Try `/dir/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/node` it should open up a node repl.  Since I suspect that's not what you want I'm going to update my answer with a build from source.

Comment: Personally I use the PPA see https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os

Comment: @generalhenry this use of `ADD` will no longer work. See latest docs: "If `<src>` is a *local* tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from *remote* URLs are **not** decompressed."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This time I tested it.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

# Create directory 
RUN mkdir -p /dir/subdir

# Make sure package is up to date
RUN apt-get update

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential openssl libssl-dev pkg-config python 

# Install nodejs
WORKDIR /dir
ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.29/node-v0.10.29.tar.gz /dir/
RUN tar -zxf node-v0.10.29.tar.gz
WORKDIR /dir/node-v0.10.29
RUN ./configure && make && make install
WORKDIR /dir

# Copy all the files 
ADD dir/subdir dir/subdir

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "/dir/subdir/index.js"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give that a try

Comment: I am getting this error on my log   Step 4 : ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz 
Invalid ADD format

Comment: nvm I forgot to add something

Comment: Yeah, I might have an error in there as well, check the add docs if you get stuck https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add

Comment: yeah, Im getting another error I dont quite understand 
Step 3 : ADD http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64.tar.gz /dir 
lchown /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/3460a5cda8f89a8495b37328eab6d3247ac5f3018ed8fa693318b98fe7ee0c4f/dir/tmp: not a directory

Comment: I would avoid ADD auto download/auto untar magic. Stick with `wget`, you won't have any surprises. Just cd `cd /dir/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64`instead of `cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64` on your exmaple and it should work.

Comment: @user3768541 See my comment on the answer for why this use of `ADD` will no longer work.

Comment: Thanks @generalhenry :)

Answer (score 2):

Docker (v1.0.0) will use `WORKDIR` for subsequent `RUN`. `cd /node-v0.10.26-linux-x64` won't work as the untar occured in `/dir`.